# Given two solutions to an initial value problem, find second order differential equations for those solutions.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Given two solutions $\phi_{1},\phi_{2}$ to an initial value problem,
>
> $x_{1}'=3x_{1}+x_{2},x_{1}(0)=1$
>
> $x_{2}'=-x_{1}+x_{2},x_{2}(0)=-1$
>
> find a second order differential equation which $\phi_{1}$ will solve. Compute $\phi_{1}'(0)$.

I am not sure how to begin with this equation. I know that you can sometimes convert a system of first order equations into a second order equation. Do I use the substitution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first equation is also $x_2=x_1'-3x_1$. Inserted into the second equation gives
$$
x_1''-3x_1'=-x_1+(x_1'-3x_1),
$$
which you can now bring into the standard form of a linear second order DE.

Comment: I understand now, thank you. But how do I compute $\phi_{1}'(0)$? Do I use this new equation?

Comment: You just take the first equation, $x_1'(0)=3x_1(0)+x_2(0)=4$.